# Companion devices logic not working on Android 9?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have implemented support for companion devices in my Android app. According to the documentation, this feature should be available on Android 8 and above. The flow works perfectly on Android 13, but on Android 9 (and possibly 10?), the pairing UI is not shown at all. Debugging when calling:

```
deviceManager.associate(pairingRequest, scanCallback, null)
```

I can see that it bails out:

[image]

This method gives me no clue:
[image]

I have a limited number of physical devices to test this on, and the current one is a Huawei which might explain that certain Google apps/services will not work. I cannot test this in an emulator as these do not support bluetooth support.

Do you know why this doesn't work on my phone?